# start sonar server in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

How can i start sonar in jenkins. i have sonar 3.1.1 in my system.
I don't have a deep knowledge in jenkins. i started junkins and added the sonar-junkins plugin. 
After that in Manage jenkins ->  Configure system i added sonar with the details as,

```
Name : sonar
Server URL : http://localhost:9000
Database URL : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
Database login : sonar
Database password : sonar
Database driver : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

then apply it and saved it.
but i cant see anything in jenkins related to sonar. I can i view the home page of sonar in jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is perfectly described on the [documentation page of the Sonar Jenkins Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341), so please read all the pages carefully and follow the guidelines step by step, and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the sonar standalone analisys you must configure all the project properties. You do that? here an example:

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=yourapp:YourApplication
sonar.projectName=YourApplication
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=yourApplication/JavaSource

# path to test source directories (optional)
sonar.tests=test

# path to project binaries (optional), for example directory of Java bytecode
sonar.binaries=YourApplication/build/classes/main

# optional comma-separated list of paths to libraries. Only path to JAR file and path to directory of classes are supported.
#sonar.libraries=path/to/library.jar,path/to/classes/dir

# The value of the property must be the key of the language.
sonar.language=java

sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

#Surefire reports
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=yourApplication/build/test-results


sonargraph.prepareForSonar=true
# Additional parameters
#sonar.my.property=value
```

In base of your version of sonar / jenkins this configuration should be slightly different
Then, if you don't make any change in the base configuration of Sonar, you don't need to put user=sonar, password=sonar